# deliver the java input arguments to another class

Tags: java, parameters

I have a question doing a Java study.
I would like to use another method by calling from the Main class.
This is the source code.

#### Java Main class

```
    public class JavaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.getNumbers();
        // calling calculation method like below
        // t1.getSum(parameters);
    }
}
```

#### Java Test class file

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public Test(){
    }

        public void getNumbers() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] ch = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i <=2 ; i++) {
            System.out.print((i+1)+" Input the Number: ");
            while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                sc.next();
                System.err.println("[ERROR]: Input again : ");
            }
            ch[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
**// devide below 4 lines to another class**
        int result = ch[0] + ch[1] + ch[2];
        int avg = (ch[0]+ch[1]+ch[2]) /3;
        System.out.println("Sum of Numbers: " + result);
        System.out.println("AVG of Numbers: " + avg);
    }   

    /* Want to do making another method like below:
    public void getSum() {
        sum of parameters from ch[0], ch[1], ch[2]
        and return the result (sum of 3 numbers)
        } */
}
```

Could you help to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the problem? I don't see anything broken with your code. Be more specific.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Thank you for replying the comment.
My point was to call the class from the Javamain class then get the arguments then deliver by calling another method
I found the answer. I'm going to put below

Answer (score 0):

Make your array an instance variable at the top of your class:

```
public class Test {
    int[] ch;

    public Test(){
   ...
```

then inside your "getNumbers()" method, use it as you were, without re-declaring it, like this:

```
ch = new int[3];
```

Then inside your get sum method, you can access the same variable to do the operations.

A instance variable is available in the entire scope of an instance of a class. So when you call the `getSum()` method on the same instance of the class, you don't need to pass back in the values that are in `ch`. You can just access the  variable and it will still contain the values that you set in the call to the `getNumbers()` method.

One issue with this is that you need to make sure `getNumbers()` is called before the `getSum()` method. If `getSum()` is the only operation you will be performing on those numbers, you could just return the sum from the `getNumbers()` method.

Comment: A class-level variable is not quite the same as a global variable.

Comment: Does Java even have global variables or functions?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I figured it out after read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### JavaMain class

```
public class JavaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         ExStudy2 e2 = new ExStudy2();
```

> int[] num = e2.getNumbers();

```
         System.out.println("Get Number is done.");

             for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
             System.out.print(i+ " Number: " +num[i] + "\t");
        }
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Sum of numbers: " + e2.getSum(num[0], num[1], num[2]));
        }
```

#### Test Class

```
public class ExStudy2 {
    public ExStudy2(){
    }
    public int[] getNumbers() {
    ... 
            return ch;
    }
    public int getSum(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a+b+c;
        } 
}
```

I didn't know that when an array Value actually returns multiple values.
Second, in the JavaMain class, call the getNumber method then assign to the array int values.

Thank you for your help.